# Opening media from google maps custom marker

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

So I'm working on a custom google maps tour type application and I'm wondering how to get media to popup when I click a link within a google maps marker.  Ideally this is what I would like to happen:
1. User clicks on marker and the normal white box comes up like on real Google Maps.
2. Within that text box I would like to have a button that will launch media that I have stored on a SQL server somewhere. This media could be audio, pictures, or video.

The code I have so far is below. If anyone could let me know how to do this, or point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Thanks

```
<!doctype  html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>HuskyWalk Application Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" conmtent="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body, #mapcanvas {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 98%;
                }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
         <script>
  var map;
  var iteCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(41.806501, -72.252769);
  //var mapCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(navigator.getCurrentPosition().coords.latitude, navigator.getCurrentPosition().coords.longitude);
  //var mapCoords = new navigator.getCurrentPosition().coords;

  function initialize() {
    //var position = new navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation(showPosition);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 18,
      center: iteCoords,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "bounds_changed", watchStart);
    var marker = createMarker();  //creates marker
    }

    function watchStart() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }

    function createMarker() {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: iteCoords,
            map: map,
            title: 'ITEB',
            });         
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", onMarker_clicked);
        return marker;
    }

    function onMarker_clicked() {
        alert(this.get('id'));
        }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
    <div>
        <p>Maps provided by Google Maps</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know there is going to need to be some stuff in the onMarker_Clicked() method most likely, I'm just not sure what.

Comment: This is the kind of box I want to pop up when the user clicks the marker. Then within that there should be a link to launch the media. http://i.imgur.com/8hFMs.png

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an InfoWindow and call its open() method from the click event handler.

See also the section in the google maps developer guide https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows